# How to accumulate not null values of each row into separate column/series?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe with a subset of columns with the form:

```
   col_A  col_B  col_C
0    NaN    1.0    NaN
1    NaN    NaN    NaN
2    NaN    NaN    2.0
3    3.0    NaN    4.0
```

I want to create a series of the notnull values for each row. For rows with multiple not null values, I want either the average or first value e.g.

```
   new_col
0      1.0
1      NaN
2      2.0
3      3.5
```

I'll eventually want to add this back to the original dataframe as a separate column so I need to persist rows with all NaN values by forward filling them e.g.

```
   new_col
0      1.0
1      1.0
2      2.0
3      3.5
```

I know how to determine if there is a not null value in the dataframe, but I don't know how to select for it:

```
df[['col_A', 'col_B', 'col_C']].count(axis=1) >= 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
df.mean(axis=1).ffill()
```

Or to restrict the columns:

```
df[['col_A', 'col_B', 'col_C']].mean(axis=1).ffill()
```

Output:

```
0    1.0
1    1.0
2    2.0
3    3.5
dtype: float64
```

Comment: For adding it as new column: `df['new_col'] = df.mean(axis=1).ffill()`